# Как сделать несколько однотипных галерей на странице?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, html5

Есть код галереи :

```
    <div id="gallery" class="gallerytest">
  <div id="thumbs" class="thumbsimg">
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/241236/pub_5cee555a14255600afbfddc6_5cf7bbf79511bd00afb4eba1/scale_1200" alt="1234">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f5/bc/60/f5bc6033d75ec2db977bdf2bffcb6991.png" alt="1235">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/9/99/Jerry_Mouse.jpg" alt="1236">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IEM9Q2fdHA0/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="1236">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="panel">
    <img id="largeImage" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IEM9Q2fdHA0/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="123">
  </div>
</div>



  .gallerytest {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.thumbsimg {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.thumbsimgg img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


#thumbs {
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#thumbs img,
#largeImage {
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#largeImage {
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#thumbs img {
  margin-right: 6px;
}



$('#thumbs').delegate('img', 'click', function() {
   $('#largeImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
 });
```

На одну галерею все работает прекрасно, но если попытаться вставить еще одну такую же галерею, js код на вторую не срабатывает. Что нужно поправить, чтобы js срабатывал на все однотипные галереи? Менял id на классы, срабатывает сразу на всех галереях.
https://jsfiddle.net/bqg0uh6z/ ссылка на код с несколькими галереями.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я в новый ответ это поместил, чтобы ты сравнил разницу. Обрати внимание на отсутствие айдишников вообще. И обрати внимание, как джаваскриптом я получил все ралереи. Это важно, потому что в цикле каждый проход создаётся ссылка на новый объект в доме, а не на один и тот же много раз. Теперь, сколько бы галерей не пришло, если они все будут иметь одинаковую структуру, то все будут работать. Как на чистом жквери сделать не знаю, не юзаю его. Но смысл, думаю, понятен.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.gallerytest')].forEach(elem => {
  let thumb = elem.children[0];
  let largeImg = elem.children[1].children[0];
  $(thumb).delegate('img', 'click', function() {
    $(largeImg).attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
  });
})
```

```css
.gallerytest {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.thumbsimg {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.thumbsimgg img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


.thumbs {
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.thumbs img,
.largeImage {
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.largeImage {
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.thumbs img {
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gallerytest">
  <div class="thumbsimg">
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/241236/pub_5cee555a14255600afbfddc6_5cf7bbf79511bd00afb4eba1/scale_1200" alt="1234">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f5/bc/60/f5bc6033d75ec2db977bdf2bffcb6991.png" alt="1235">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/9/99/Jerry_Mouse.jpg" alt="1236">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IEM9Q2fdHA0/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="1236">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <img class="largeImage" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IEM9Q2fdHA0/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="123">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gallerytest">
  <div class="thumbsimg">
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/241236/pub_5cee555a14255600afbfddc6_5cf7bbf79511bd00afb4eba1/scale_1200" alt="1234">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f5/bc/60/f5bc6033d75ec2db977bdf2bffcb6991.png" alt="1235">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/9/99/Jerry_Mouse.jpg" alt="1236">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IEM9Q2fdHA0/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="1236">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IEM9Q2fdHA0/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="123">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ты волшебник! Это то что было нужно! Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Я с вёрсткой не стал разбиратсья, но дело в том, что айдишник - уникальная штука. Ну и жквери обращается у тебя по айдишнику. В общем, вот так работает, только с вёрсткой разобраться надо. Во второй галерее изменил все айдишники, добавив 2 к имени

```js
$('#thumbs').delegate('img', 'click', function() {
   $('#largeImage').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
 });
 
 $('#thumbs2').delegate('img', 'click', function() {
   $('#largeImage2').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
 });
```

```css
  .gallerytest {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.thumbsimg {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.thumbsimgg img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}


#thumbs {
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#thumbs2 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#thumbs img,
#largeImage,
#largeImage {
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#largeImage {
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#largeImage2 {
  margin-left: 35px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#thumbs img {
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gallery" class="gallerytest">
  <div id="thumbs" class="thumbsimg">
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/241236/pub_5cee555a14255600afbfddc6_5cf7bbf79511bd00afb4eba1/scale_1200" alt="1234">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f5/bc/60/f5bc6033d75ec2db977bdf2bffcb6991.png" alt="1235">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/9/99/Jerry_Mouse.jpg" alt="1236">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IEM9Q2fdHA0/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="1236">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="panel">
    <img id="largeImage2" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IEM9Q2fdHA0/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="123">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="gallery2" class="gallerytest">
  <div id="thumbs2" class="thumbsimg">
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/241236/pub_5cee555a14255600afbfddc6_5cf7bbf79511bd00afb4eba1/scale_1200" alt="1234">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/f5/bc/60/f5bc6033d75ec2db977bdf2bffcb6991.png" alt="1235">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/9/99/Jerry_Mouse.jpg" alt="1236">
    </div>
    <div class="thumbsimgg">
      <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IEM9Q2fdHA0/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="1236">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="panel2">
    <img id="largeImage" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IEM9Q2fdHA0/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="123">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Дело в том, что код формируется в вордпрессе. И таких галерей может быть неизвестное кол-во. Неужто нужно будет под каждую галерею писать новый jquery код?

Comment: @Shiho а как из вордпреса приходит? ВП же не даёт одинаковые айдишники всем галереям?

Comment: Sazanov Даёт, потому что он задаётся в html - создан один блок на вывод. А вот картинки выводятся кодом php с админки вордпресса. И таких  галерей может быть сколько угодно и нужно написать код так, чтобы js распознавал разные галереи. Можно сделать так, чтобы у каждой галереи id в html были разные, но как это учесть в js, если кол-во галерей неизвестно?

Comment: @Shiho не ясно. Если в документе встречаются 2 одинаковых айдишника, это не валидный хтмл в принципе. Если есть вариант (я в ВП в жизни не работал) иметь на выходе несколько галерей с абсолютно одинаковой структуры и дать как-то классы им одинаковые, то нужно проходиться кодом по всем таким галереям и вытаскивать элементы и навешивать события какие-то. Блин, постораюсь чуть позже код примерный сделать.

Comment: Буду благодарен :)

Comment: Добавил ответ. Если админы посчитают 2 ответа излишними в этой ситуации, то сорян. Я подумал, разницу в подходах надо показать наглядно.